What are the measures to determine Depression, Anxiety and Stress from 68-facial landmark data (CK+)?
i have been trying to find any kind of information or resource about this for coding in jupyter. I have already took out the landmarks using dlib python library of images and saved them in a csv. And trying to figure out Depression, Anxiety and Stress from these. Can anyone help me?
Tried differentiating by using emotions that are labeled in CK+ dataset. But that's not what I am required to do. I want to determine Depression, Anxiety and Stress from landmarks only.

Are you basing this on a paper? Has someone created a labeled data set for this purpose? If not based on a labeled data set, how would something like this even be plausible? What research have you already done on your own? Also I don't see why it's relevant what IDE you are using.
